# How we can combine the selector in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

Suppose that I want 3 data from 3 different reducers.

In general I can do something like this!!

```
const data1 = useSelector((state: any) => state?.reducer1);
const data2 = useSelector((state: any) => state?.reducer2);
const data3 = useSelector((state: any) => state?.reducer3);
```

So how can I achieve the same result with single `useSelector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const dataState = useSelector((state: any) => ({reducer1: state?.reducer1, reducer2: state?.reducer2, reducer3: state?.reducer3}));

const data1 = dataState.reducer1;
const data2 = dataState.reducer2;
const data3 = dataState.reducer3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the deconstruction assignment for your state such as:

```js
const { reducer1, reducer2, reducer3 } = useSelector((state: any) =>
  ({
    reducer1: state?.reducer1,
    reducer2: state?.reducer2,
    reducer3: state?.reducer3
  }));
```